# Missing orientation detection after installation of W10 education N

Tags: windows, windows-10, hid, display-rotation

After upgrading to Windows 10 education N Edition from W10 Home, support for many features concerning convertible laptops (orientation, keyboard lock, etc.) became unavailable. Updating manufacturer drivers and editing with Windows registry didn't fix the problem. How do I activate these laptop specific features?

Answer (score 0):

Optional: Get hold of mfplatt.dll and put it in a PATH dir, which is needed to add optional features in windows 10 if your installation didn't include it.

Install the Windows 10 media feature pack corresponding to your windows build (obtained by eg. winver.exe found in path).